# Content of Ext.Carousel ist not visible

Tags: javascript, iphone, extjs, sencha-touch

I have a problem using the Carousel component of the Sencha Touch Framework. I have a component extended from a simple Panel that does the following:

```
    var cardItems = [];

    this.basicCard = new Ext.Component({
        scroll: 'vertical',
        html: 'Hello Carousel 1!'
    });

    this.basicCard2 = new Ext.Component({
        scroll: 'vertical',
        html: 'Hello Carousel 2!'
    });

    cardItems.push(this.basicCard);

    cardItems.push(this.basicCard2);

    this.carousel = new Ext.Carousel({
        items: cardItems
    });

    this.items = [this.carousel];
```

Unfortunately, when I make this Panel visible, the content of the Carousel isn't shown, though I can see the generated tags with the developer tools of my browser.

The official Carousel demo works fine in my browser and if I replace the Carousel by a Panel, it's content is also visible, so the rest of the code should be correct.
Can you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is the real problem you are facing but it shouldn't be in the code you posted. Because I just tested here at [jsfiddle.net/r423w](http://jsfiddle.net/r423w/) and your code works (even hiding the panel and showing it a second later).

Comment: I now found out that it is not possible to nest a carousel in a panel, unless the panel has a proper layout. In my minimal example, the outer panel didn't have a layout, so it didn't work.

Comment: The panel always needs a layout if you have items in it. You can check that in the introduction of Panel's API: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.Panel
If you don't need more answers to this question you could accept the answer that best fit your needs, or write an answser yourself, this is to let know the community that this is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

My advice to you to put your carousel card contents in panels.

```
this.cardItems = [];
this.cardItems.push(new Ext.Panel({
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            html: "Your HTML here"
        }));
```

and after you finish pushing cards
do the following

```
this.carousel.add(this.cardItems);
this.carousel.doLayout();
this.doLayout();
```

I know carousel component is difficult to figure out as I also spent hours on it but I'm sure you'll manage when you push harder.